# How to make System.Import non-blocking in Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm splitting my React JS code as per https://medium.com/@apostolos/server-side-rendering-code-splitting-and-hot-reloading-with-react-router-v4-87239cfc172c so users don't have to download the whole app upfront. This works great. What's not great about this solution is that when a user clicks on an area that is not yet loaded they have to wait for it to load.

My initial idea was to pre-load the other chunks in the background. Unfortunately the browser (or is it webpack?) does not render anything until these background calls are finished.

Is there a way to call `System.import` in such a way that it does not block rendering?

Thanks